# Restructuring a time series dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am trying to download information from the [JHU on pandemic infections](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19). I am interested in getting the number of daily reported cases per country.

To start with, from the original database, I can find a df with this structure:

```
 `Country/Region`   Lat   Long `1/22/20` `1/23/20` `1/24/20`
 <chr>            <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1  Afghanistan       33.9  67.7          0         0         0
2 Albania           41.2  20.2          0         0         0
3 Algeria           28.0   1.66         0         0         0
4 Andorra           42.5   1.52         0         0         0
5 Angola           -11.2  17.9          0         0         0
6 Antigua and Bar~  17.1 -61.8          0         0         0
# ... with 592 more variables: 1/25/20 <dbl>, 1/26/20 <dbl>, 1/27/20 <dbl>,...
```

But I would like to get something similar to this:

```
head(example)

    Country/Region  Date                Cases
1   Afghanistan      2020-01-22             2
2   Afghanistan      2020-01-23             3
3   Afghanistan      2020-01-24             4
.
.
.
100 Albania          2020-01-22             0
101 Albania          2020-01-23             1
102 Albania          2020-01-24             0

#and so on with the rest of the countries
```

Any idea on how to do so in RStudio?

[Update]

I had tried with this code,suggested by @akrun:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
  result <- originaldf %>%
  select(-c(Lat, Long)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -`Country/Region`, names_to = 'Date', 
               values_to = 'Cases') %>%
  group_by(`Country/Region`, Date = mdy(Date)) %>%
  summarise(Cases = sum(Cases, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

The result is as follows:

```
  `Country/Region` Date        Cases
1 Afghanistan      2020-03-15      1 #this row is fictitious
2 Afghanistan      2020-03-16     18
3 Afghanistan      2020-03-17     20
4 Afghanistan      2020-03-18     24
5 Afghanistan      2020-03-19     25
6 Afghanistan      2020-03-20     29
```

Even so, if you check the original dataset, this result is acumulating the cases day by day. A proper result should be like this:

```
  `Country/Region` Date        Cases
1 Afghanistan      2020-03-15      1
2 Afghanistan      2020-03-16     17
3 Afghanistan      2020-03-17      2
4 Afghanistan      2020-03-18      4
5 Afghanistan      2020-03-19      1
6 Afghanistan      2020-03-20      4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could reshape to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and then do a group by `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
out <- df1 %>%
   select(-c(Lat, Long, `Province/State`)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -c(`Country/Region`), names_to = 'Date', 
           values_to = 'Cases') %>%
    mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) %>%
    arrange(`Country/Region`, Date) %>%    
    group_by(`Country/Region`) %>%
    mutate(Count = c(0, diff(Cases))) %>%
   group_by(Date, .add = TRUE) %>%
   summarise(Count = sum(Count, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
> tail(out)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  `Country/Region` Date       Count
  <chr>            <date>     <dbl>
1 Zimbabwe         2021-09-02   158
2 Zimbabwe         2021-09-03   213
3 Zimbabwe         2021-09-04    94
4 Zimbabwe         2021-09-05   125
5 Zimbabwe         2021-09-06   121
6 Zimbabwe         2021-09-07   125
> head(out)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  `Country/Region` Date       Cases
  <chr>            <date>     <int>
1 Afghanistan      2020-01-22     0
2 Afghanistan      2020-01-23     0
3 Afghanistan      2020-01-24     0
4 Afghanistan      2020-01-25     0
5 Afghanistan      2020-01-26     0
6 Afghanistan      2020-01-27     0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv", check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: It is necessary to load `lubridate` too. Thanks!

Comment: @JoséRojas sorry, forgot to add that library.  Updated

Comment: What the code is doing is accumulating the contagions. That is, if 1 case was recorded on January 22, 2020 and the next day 2 cases, the new df records the 3 cumulative cases on January 23, 2020. My intention is not that, but simply to count the cases per day. I have gone through the code to try to change it towards what I want but I can't find a way. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: @JoséRojas The code in my solution get the total number of Cases per Country/Region and Date.  I think your description is also `simply to count the cases per day`

Comment: @JoséRojas the link you showed had multiple datasets.  Which one is used by you

Comment: Yes. But, as I describe to you in the previous comment, after reviewing the result in detail, the code is accumulating the cases and not just counting them.

Comment: @JoséRojas when you say count, do you take the `0` values into consideration

Comment: The path to the dataset I'm using is `COVID-19-master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv`

Comment: @JoséRojas Perhaps you meant `summarise(Cases = sum(Cases > 0, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')` try the update

Comment: @JoséRojas from the data you linked, I get 0 counts for Afghanistan

Comment: @JoséRojas is the expected output in your post correct as I can't replicate those numbers from the data

Comment: If you note when seeing the `tail`, the cases never go down, they are always increasing because they are actually adding up the cases of the day and of the previous days. You can try this code to see it better: `ggplot(df) +
  aes(x = Date, y = CasesxPopxWeek, colour = Country) +
  geom_line(size = 0.5) +
  scale_color_hue(direction = 1) +
  theme_minimal()`
I have added an update to the question. Thank u so much for ur time.

Comment: @JoséRojas It is getting the sum of Counts by day and also by Country.  So, whatever values are there in each day (if there are multiple rows are getting summed up

Comment: @JoséRojas Are you saying that the values in the data is cumulative sum.  So, we need to get the original values.  Then, we need a `diff` on those

Answer (score 0):

Use tidyr package

```
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::gather(key = "Date", value = "Cases", `1/22/20`:`1/24/20`)
```